# How I can enable ADSL conection on Fedora 18 and on Debian 7.2?

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, adsl

About Fedora 18:
The command `adsl-setup` doesn't exist, and how I cannot any connection established I can't install any package.

Debian 7:
The method using the `pppoeconf` doesn't work, my media of installation was inserted.

Comment: Please explain what you did, what commands you ran and with what options. Also, how is your ADSL set up? Assuming your router is correctly configured, Linux should be able to connect out of the box when you connect your cable. I have used ADSL connections with Debian, Ubuntu, Mint and SuSe and have never needed either of the two programs you mentioned.

Comment: @terdon By the router I can connect, to cable or wireless, but if connect the cable from modem i can not, and unfortunately do not have access to the modem, the gateway that I have don't allows me to enter and configure. And how you set up the ADSL connection on Debian?

Comment: Do you mean entering your username and password to connect to your ISP? That has nothing to do with Debian, it should be done through your modem/router. Please [edit] your question and add more information (such as the limitations you have). Explain what exactly you need to do (e.g. you need to enter the ppoe username and password) etc.

Comment: @terdon I will change my network structure, You right should be done through modem/router. Thanks by your attention.